# Scraping web page source code for windows phone application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, event-handling, webclient

I am extremely new to developing with C# for WP7. I am trying to write a simple app which will take the url from textBox1 and update the Text in textBlock1 with the source code for that page when button1 is pressed.

The part I am stuck on is how to pass the Result in DownloadStringCallback2 back to the LoadSiteContent function so it can be returned as the variable sourceCode.

Code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace TestApp1
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string url = textBox1.Text;
            string sourceCode = LoadSiteContent(url);
            textBlock1.Text = sourceCode;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// method for retrieving information from a specified URL
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url">url to retrieve data from</param>
        /// <returns>source code of URL</returns>
        public string LoadSiteContent(string url)
        {
            //create a new WebClient object
            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            //create a byte array for holding the returned data
            string sourceCode = "Fail";
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += new    DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringCallback2);
           client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));

           //use the UTF8Encoding object to convert the byte
           //array into a string
           //UTF8Encoding utf = new UTF8Encoding();

           //return the converted string
           //return utf.GetString(html, 0, html.Length);
           return sourceCode;
        }

        private static void DownloadStringCallback2(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           // If the request was not canceled and did not throw
           // an exception, display the resource.
           if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
           {
               string textString = (string)e.Result;
           } 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it like you'd want to, because al web requests in WP7 (silverlight) are asynchronous.
This means that the code doesn't stop while downloading a webpage and continue when it's finished in the same line and function, instead it creates a new thread, downloads the file and calls the callback function.

You would have to continue in the callback function (DownloadStringCallback2 in your case).
In that function you'd have to put the source code (e.Result) into the textbox.

May I add to that if you ever get a Cross-Thread exception or if you want to keep the UI decently usable while executing tasks, you can use this command:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action (() => LoadContent("http://www.google.com")));
```

This command fixes the Cross-Thread exception (if I remember correctly) and executes the code on a different thread than the UI thread, thus maintaining a stable UI.

**EDIT** I think your code should look like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string url = textBox1.Text;
        LoadSiteContent(url);
    }

    public string LoadSiteContent(string url)
    {
        //create a new WebClient object
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new    DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringCallback2);
       client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
    }

    private static void DownloadStringCallback2(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       // If the request was not canceled and did not throw
       // an exception, display the resource.
       if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
       {
           textBlock1.Text = (string)e.Result;
           //If you get the cross-thread exception then use the following line instead of the above
           //Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action (() => textBlock1.Text = (string)e.Result));
       } 
    }
```

Comment: I updated the callback function to now look like:
`       private static void DownloadStringCallback2(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // If the request was not canceled and did not throw
            // an exception, display the resource.
            if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
            {
                textBlock1.Text = (string)e.Result;
            }
        }`

I am getting the error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TestApp1.MainPage.textBlock1'

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The reason it says that is because you're trying to edit a textBlock1 that's on MainPage, and because your Callback function is static, it doesn't know textBlock1. My method of dealing with this was using a delegate. Delegates are really useful in wp7 because of the asynchronous events, I recommend you look them up if they're unknown to you. You can also add a `public static MainPage mainPage;` and fill it in the constructor like `mainPage = this;` then you can use it to fill the textBlock1 with `mainPage.textBlock1.Text = (string)e.Result;`. There could be easier ways, but I can't test atm.

Comment: I just realized I never followed up to this post. Your advice was very helpful and I would vote up your answer but I am a new user. Thank you for the response.